# How to sync files between two folders and replace when the date stamp is changed in source location usning python?

Tags: python

I'm trying for a Python script that will sync files between location A and B (includes sub folders) and also if the date stamp is changed in source location it should replace that file in destination as well and few arrays to ignore few file types like *.bin, grim.txt and Scripts folder.

```py
from dirsync import sync
sync('C:\FOLDER_A', 'E:\FOLDER_B', 'sync', purge = True)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: could you give a little bit more info on the code snipped? what is the problem / not working?

Comment: above code is only able to sync but am unable to find any info on how to integrate other requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already seem to have installed suitable package for what you intend to do. Now you could simply write

```py
import dirsync
source, dest = 'dir_a', 'dir_b'
dirsync.sync(source, dest, 'sync', verbose=True) # verbose gives you more info on what has been done
```

To exclude file types like *.bin, use `regex` patterns:

```py
pattern = ('^.*\.bin$',)
dirsync.sync(source, dest, 'sync', verbose=True, exclude=pattern)
```

More info on e.g. dirsync.sync options can be found on the [package homepage](https://bitbucket.org/tkhyn/dirsync/src/default/). If you want to know the options work 'in action', have a look into the `tests` folder of the dirsync repo, e.g. [here for the regex patterns](https://bitbucket.org/tkhyn/dirsync/src/default/tests/regexfilters.py); helper for regex patterns [here](https://regex101.com/).